# How to log number with commas as thousands separators?

Tags: python, logging, string-formatting

The time has come to convert all prints into logging calls in a library I'm maintaining.  Some of the print calls are using `str.format`, like this (simplified):

```
>>> n = 4000000
>>> print(f"this bird wouldn't voom if you put {n:,} volts through it!")
this bird wouldn't voom if you put 4,000,000 volts through it!
```

When I try to log it:

```
>>> log.warning("this bird wouldn't voom if you put %d, volts through it!", n)
WARNING:root:this bird wouldn't voom if you put 4000000, volts through it!
```

Seems this is not specifying the thousands separator correctly.  How do you specify the thousands separator when using the %-formatting syntax which Python's stdlib logging module necessitates?

Currently using this workaround, which does give the desired output, but seems wrong since the variable is formatted first using `str.format` and then formatted as a string again, instead of logging as a number directly:

```
>>> log.warning("this bird wouldn't voom if you put %s volts through it!", format(n, ','))
WARNING:root:this bird wouldn't voom if you put 4,000,000 volts through it!
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: use a [`logging.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) with `style="{"`

Comment: So, maybe something [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles) will help.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I've tried that in the past, and couldn't get it working.  The `{` style is used for the template format itself, but not for the parameters of the actual message.  But I may have missed something - if you can get it working, by all means add an answer.

Comment: I've tried to get this to work, myself, also coming up short.  I recommend you continue with your "cheating" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a limitation with `logging` and it's actually mentioned in (at least one place in) the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug):

> `logging.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> Logs a message with level `DEBUG` on the root logger. The msg is the message format string, and the args are the arguments which are merged into **`msg` using the string formatting operator**. (Note that this means that you can use keywords in the format string, together with a single dictionary argument.)

(emphasis mine)

But the string formatting operator `%` doesn't support [thousand seperators](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

You could however adapt a recipe from the official `cookbook`:

```
import logging

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, fmt, args):
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.args = args

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fmt.format(*self.args)

class StyleAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, logger, extra=None):
        super(StyleAdapter, self).__init__(logger, extra or {})

    def log(self, level, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(level):
            msg, kwargs = self.process(msg, kwargs)
            self.logger._log(level, Message(msg, args), (), **kwargs)

logger = StyleAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__))

def main():
    # this changed
    logger.warning("this bird wouldn't voom if you put {:,} volts through it!", 4000000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

> `WARNING:__main__:` this bird wouldn't voom if you put 4,000,000 volts through it!

This is actually copied verbatim (I just changed the message) from the last example in the ["Use of alternative formatting styles"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles) section.

---

Personally I would just go with your `format(n, ',')` solution. It may not be perfect but it doesn't require setting up a custom `LoggerAdapter` to print a different thousand seperator.

Comment: Ugh, the `StyleAdapter` is really ugly.  Not cool to access protected `self.logger._log`.  I guess I'll just stick with the workaround.  Thx!